# Does constructing an iostream (c++) read data from the hard drive into memory?

Tags: c++, iostream

When I construct an iostream when say opening a file will this always read the entire file from the hard disk and then put it into memory, or is it streamed in and buffered by the OS on demand?

I ask because one way to check if a file exists is to see if opening it fails, but I fear if the files I am opening are very large then this take a long time if iostream must read the entire file in on open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not read the entire file into memory when you open it. It will read your file in chunks though, but I believe this process will not start until you read the first byte. Also these chunks are relatively small (on the order of 4-128 kibibytes in size), and the fact it does this will speed things up greatly if you are reading the file sequentially.

In a test on my Linux box (well, Linux VM) simply opening the file only results in the OS `open` system call, but no `read` system call. It doesn't start reading anything from the file until the first attempt to read from the stream. And then it reads 8191 (why 8191? that seems a very strange number) byte chunks as I read the file in.

Comment: Out of curiosity how are you testing that? Are you stepping through the linux source with a debugger? I realize how absurd that sounds, but I can't think of how else you could be monitoring system calls.

Comment: @Avram: There is a nice utility for Linux called `strace`.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether a file exists can be done like this if you want to use [boost](http://www.boost.org).

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

bool fileExists = boost::filesystem::exists("foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file is a bad way of testing if the file exists - all it does is tell you if you can open it. Opening might fail for  a number of reasons, typically because you don't have read permission, but the file will still exist. It is usually better to use an operating system specific function to test for existence. And no, opening an fstream will not cause the contents to be read.

Comment: If my program doesn't have permission it is the same as if the file doesn't exist to me.

Nevertheless what would you recommend for Windows. I don't really need compatability with anything older than xp sp2, or any other platform.

Comment: I was thinking this too. I was just disappointed there was no standard C or C++ means to tell if a file existed.

Comment: @Avram: Maybe it's even better to assume the file exists and throw when you actually need it and that operation fails.

Comment: Well what I'm doing is have this Import class that imports data, and the user can set a bunch of environment variables for each Import object. When the user requests some data from a file it will search all those paths for the file. So internally I need some way of checking if files exist. Sometimes the next operation is to open them, while other times the string is passed into a GDI+ Bitmap constructor, so I can't condense the find full path and open operations into one.

Comment: @Avram There are several ways of doing this in Windows - one simple way is to use GetFileAttributes and see if it returns an error, which it will if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is, when you open a file, the corresponding data structures for the process opening the file are populated which include file pointer, file descriptor, v node etc.

Now one can read and write to a file using buffered streams (fwrite , fread) or using system calls (read and write).

When we use buffered streams, we buffer the data and then write or read it[This is done for efficiency puposes]. This statement itself means that the whole file is not read into memory but certain bytes are read into buffer and then made available.

In case of sys calls such as read and write , kernel level buffering is done (using fsync one can flush out kernel buffer too), but data is actually read and written to the device .file

```
checking existance of file

#include < sys/stat.h >

int main(){
struct stat file_i;
std::string f("myfile.txt");
if (stat(f.c_str(),&file_i) != 0){
   cout << "File not found" << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: If dont want to use boost, you can use functions in "sys/stat" header.